# MuraCMS and ColdFusion2021 Upgrade

Tags: iis, coldfusion, mura

I just recently upgraded my CF from 10 to 2021 Enterprise. We are running muraCMS as our framework on the site. My CF files open fine, but my mura templates are giving me errors and I cannot access the full site. I also cannot access the mura Admin page either. My CF site is now pointing to the default server port, 8500. It was using 1000. I have changed my bindings to 8500 for mura, but it still will not connect. I am almost thinking there is a setting in one of the mura files that is pointing to 1000, but I cannot find it. I need help, I have until Sunday night to get this working and I am at a loss. Does anyone have experience with IIS/CF2021/MuraCMS that can lend a hand?

Comment: Do you seen an error message? Is something written to the log files under /cfusion/logs/

Comment: Have you posted this issue on the MuraCMS support portal? https://support.murasoftware.com/portal/en/signin

Comment: Enable debugging in the Mura configuration file and reload your site. See what information that provides. https://docs.murasoftware.com/v6/installation-setup/settingsinicfm-reference/

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!  I have looked at the CF logs and its not stating anything in regards to mura.  I have not submitted anything with mura support, but will look into doing that now.  And looking to see if I have debugging enabled in mura.  I reverted my site back to CF10 and its working.  I really really appreciate the input!  Will try again soon once I look into all suggestions above.  Thank you again!